# Inserting into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I"m trying to populate a UITableView with contents of a file. Or at least that's my ultimate goal but for testing I just wanted to insert strings to test it out. I have a read and write button connected to my ViewController.h as both @propery and IBAction to implement the press and I have a UITableView property

This is my implementation for the read and write button.

```
- (IBAction)readtofile:(id)sender {

    [_readview beginUpdates];
    NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/TestFile.txt"];
    NSString* data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:docPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:data,data,data, nil];
    [_readview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_readview endUpdates];

}

- (IBAction)writetofile:(id)sender {
    NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/TestFile.txt"];

    NSString* data = @"hello world";
    [data writeToFile:docPath
    atomically:YES
      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
         error:NULL];
}
```

EDIT: Here's the updated code with Vadian's answer. But the UITableView still isn't being populated 
`ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *readview;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *items;
- (IBAction)readFromFile:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)writeToFile:(id)sender;


@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.items = @[@"hello world",@"good bye world"];
    _readview.dataSource = self;
}

- (IBAction)readFromFile:(id)sender {
    NSURL *docURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                             inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                    appropriateForURL:nil
                                                               create:NO
                                                                error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFile.plist"];
     NSData* propertyListData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: docURL];
     NSError *error;
     self.items = (NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: propertyListData
                                                                              options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                                                               format:NULL
                                                                                error:nil];
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
     } else {
         [_readview reloadData];
     }
}

- (IBAction)writeToFile:(id)sender {
    NSURL *docURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                             inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                    appropriateForURL:nil
                                                               create:NO
                                                                error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFile.plist"];
     NSError *error;
     NSData *propertyListData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:self.items
                                                                           format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                                          options:0
                                                                            error:&error];
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
     } else {
         [propertyListData writeToURL:docURL atomically:YES];
     }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [_readview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row
                                  ];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

It's crashing inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. `List[2558:545971] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:],` So I'm not sure how to implement that method properly.
This is my UI layout. 
[image]

Comment: It crashes cause your tableView dataSource isn't in sync with insertion

Comment: @MarekH I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: It's documented. Read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/filling_a_table_with_data?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but almost any line of the both methods is unusable.

First of all you need an `NSMutableArray` for the data source.

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *items;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` populate the array with your demo data

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"hello world"]];
```

Let's start with the save method. Serialize `items` as property list and save it to disk. In iOS you have to use the `NSFileManager` API to get the (current) documents folder.

```
- (IBAction)writeToFile:(id)sender {
    NSURL *docURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                   appropriateForURL:nil
                                                              create:NO
                                                               error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFile.plist"];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *propertyListData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:items
                                                                          format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                                         options:0
                                                                           error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        [propertyListData writeToURL:docURL atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

The read method does the same in reverse order: Read the data, deserialize it to `NSMutableArray` and assign the result to the data source array. Then reload the table view.

```
- (IBAction)readFromFile:(id)sender {

    NSURL *docURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                   appropriateForURL:nil
                                                              create:NO
                                                               error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFile.plist"];
    NSData* propertyListData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: docURL];
    NSError *error;
    self.items = (NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: propertyListData
                                                                             options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                                                              format:NULL
                                                                               error:nil];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        [_readview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: So it seems to read and write fine but it doesn't populate the UITableView* _readview.. I don't know how calling reloadData will just insert data into the tableview..

Comment: You have to adjust the table view datasource methods (`numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and you have to connect the data source of the table view to the view controller (control drag form the table view to the controller and select `dataSource`). Yes, `reloadData` inserts the rows.

Comment: Edited my question with implementing numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm not sure what you mean by connect the data of the table view to the view controller though.. Do you mean connecting it as a property?

Comment: You have to change the interface to `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSTableViewDataSource>` and you can also set the delegate in code, in `viewDidLoad` add `self.readview.dataSource = self`

Comment: I edited the question to insert the initial code. Without this code the question makes no sense for other readers.

Comment: I made the adjustments you have said. But now it's crashing in my implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm not sure to to implement that method.

Comment: Make sure that the `identifier` of the cell (`Cell`) is set properly in Interface Builder.

Comment: So do I have to create an individual Cell on top of the UITableView? Because I don't see an identifier property on the Table itself

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that. Drag a cell into the table view of the canvas and set the identifier.

Comment: Can you revise your answer though? Because my question was about insering into a UITableView but your answer is about reading and writing data, it covers nothing about implementing UITableViewDataSource delegages

Comment: The datasource methods in your code are basically correct. As I said you have to set the identifier of the cell to `Cell` in Interface Builder. And it’s bad practice to use the outlet as table view reference. Use always the given `tableView` parameter.